# How do I get a Recycler from a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) of `addView()` from `LayoutManager` says:

> Add a view to the currently attached RecyclerView if needed.
>   LayoutManagers should use this method to add views obtained from a
>   RecyclerView.Recycler using getViewForPosition(int).

But [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) doesn't seem to expose a method to get its `RecyclerView.Recycler`. Am I missing something here? How to get an instance of it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I get a Recycler?"

Comment: I was trying to get all views bound ready to be measured from the `RecyclerView` from outside the `LayoutManager`. I figured I'd iterate over all positions using `getViewForPosition`.